# Error trying to buid a Nexus 6 kernel: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: android, c, linux

I'm trying to build a kernel following this (https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels) for my Nexus 6 (shamu) (marshmallow). When I type "sudo make", I'm getting this error:

```
arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.c: In function ‘dma_generic_alloc_coherent’:
arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.c:105:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
error, forbidden warning: pci-dma.c:105
scripts/Makefile.build:308: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.o'
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:455: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'arch/x86/kernel'
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
Makefile:799: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'arch/x86'
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

I have not written that file, so I don't know what causes the error, that part of the file is

```
void *dma_generic_alloc_coherent(struct device *dev, size_t size,
                 dma_addr_t *dma_addr, gfp_t flag,
                 struct dma_attrs *attrs)
{
    unsigned long dma_mask;
    struct page *page;
    unsigned int count = PAGE_ALIGN(size) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
    dma_addr_t addr;

    dma_mask = dma_alloc_coherent_mask(dev, flag);

    flag |= __GFP_ZERO;
again:
    page = NULL;
    /* CMA can be used only in the context which permits sleeping */
    if (flag & __GFP_WAIT)
        page = dma_alloc_from_contiguous(dev, count, get_order(size));
    /* fallback */
    if (!page)
        page = alloc_pages_node(dev_to_node(dev), flag, get_order(size));
    if (!page)
        return NULL;    

    addr = page_to_phys(page);
    if (addr + size > dma_mask) {
        __free_pages(page, get_order(size));

        if (dma_mask < DMA_BIT_MASK(32) && !(flag & GFP_DMA)) {
            flag = (flag & ~GFP_DMA32) | GFP_DMA;
            goto again;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    *dma_addr = addr;
    return page_address(page);
}
```

And the line 105 is:

```
        page = dma_alloc_from_contiguous(dev, count, get_order(size));
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you sure you want to build an x86 kernel?

Comment: Felix, I don't know, I'm following the guide, should I change the compiler? how?

Comment: I assume the Nexus6 is an `arm` device, but the messages you show indicate that code for `x86` is compiled, so you probably use your host's normal C compiler creating `x86` code. You need a cross compiler targeting your device, see e.g. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Comment: @FelixPalmen you were right, thank you!